# Loading Fragment if not Null - Android

Tags: android, fragment, oncreate, onresume

I need help about an issue, in my android app that I am working on, I am navigating between `Fragment`s all the time. I use the code to navigate between `Fragment`s.

```
newsFeedFragment fragment = new newsFeedFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

With the code above, navigating to the news feed fragment loads from "`onCreate`". HI need that if the fragment was loaded before, it should show the previously loaded page, the `onCreate` should be skipped but the `onResume` not. However, if the `Fragment` was not loaded before the `Fragment` should be loaded for the first time.

Could anyone help me about making this happen?

Thank you very much

Comment: for you need to set some id for each fragment then search for that fragment if it exist load it else create new then load it.If you want code I can give some .

Comment: Hello dex, it would be great if you could show me a sample, I am a bit new in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding TAG to your fragments. Where ever you add a fragment to your view do this like the following:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.something, new SomeFragment(),"SOMETAG").commit();
```

and where ever you want to check whether this fragment is already exists to prevent reloading it add the following check:

```
SomeFragment sf = (SomeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SOMETAG");
if(sf != null)
{
   //the condition when the fragment is already exists
}
else
{
   //the condition when the fragment is not loaded
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pooya, in the if conditions how should I retrieve the fragment if it exists already, and how if it doesnt? Is there any difference? Sorry for asking too many questions.